# PHP force download base64image

Tags: php, download, base64

I want to offer a PNG image to download only for some users, and the image should not be located anywhere, so the users should not see it's path.

That's why I inserted it to the download.php as a base64 image. The problem is, however the image is offered for download, but it shows 0 B size when downloaded.

```
    $base64strImg = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAxoAAARjCAIAAABnqMWCAAAACXBIWXM...';
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myimage.png');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile(base64_decode($base64strImg));
            exit;
```

Not sure where is the problem, if it can't handle big image or why it can't be downloaded.

I also tried this way:

```
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.png"');
            header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
            echo base64_decode($base64strImg);
```

Now the image has correct size, but still, can't be opened after download. The image viewer says unsupported format.

And third option - without decoding, it also has a correct size, but still can't be opened.

```
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.png');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($base64strImg));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        echo $base64strImg;
        exit;
```

Comment: The data URI prefix `data:image/png;base64,` isn't valid base64 data. And `readfile()` would throw a warning if used this way.

Comment: why not? I got this from online image to base64 converter. Readfile throws no error, it offers to download the image normally, but the image can't be opened after download

Comment: I also tried base64_decode and then file_put_contents, this works, but this will create the image on the server and doesn't offer to download. I don't want to create the image anywhere, just to download it

Comment: just remove the `data:image/png;base64,` part, then it will work

Comment: also set the content type to image/png else it will show an ugly icon when prompting to download

Comment: thank you, I updated my code and now it seems working fine

Answer (score 3):

According to advice from @Lawrence I updated my code and this way it works:

```
  $resultimg = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,","",$base64strImg);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.png"');
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        echo base64_decode($resultimg);
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to do all that you can just upload image and restrict access to it by htaccess or permissions and use readfile with the headers in download.php and check if the user has the permission to download the file .

Comment: Yeah, but each user has a special url with hash, which works for 24h only. If the image will be physically on server, they can access it any time or share the link. So you mean to restrict access to that image in htaccess for all, and to allow/restrict it in PHP according to hash and time. Not a bad idea too, but I see here more effort as in my current solution.

Comment: i think this is the best solution for you situation you just restrict access for all 
and in php file write it like this 
if(userHasPermission and timeIsRight) {
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.png"');
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile(path);
}
exit();
and this will save you a lot of time if you have different images for users and multiple images you just insert the path into database now you have to edit download.php manually every time you have a new image .